# Существует ли документация discord.py переведенная на русский?

Tags: python, discord.py

Такая существует или придется использовать оригинал на английском?

Answer (score 5):

Нет, на русском её не существует. Но не бойтесь читать её на английском. Почти все документации простые и требуют лишь основных, базовых знаний английского языка.

Comment: +1. @Автору вопроса: в качестве бонуса вы немного улучшаете ваш английский (если у вас начальный уровень)